# How to remove nan value from a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop, nan

I have a list whose name is Ave. Ave[0] is shown below:

```
[array([ nan]),
 array([ 0.03030303]),
 array([ 0.025]),
 array([ 0.03546099]),
 array([ 0.02877698]),
 array([ 0.05343511]),
 array([ nan]),
 array([ nan])]
```

I need to remove the nan value from each list in the Ave.
my code works slowly:

```
for j in range(len(Ave)):
    c=0
    while c<8:
        for i in range(len(Ave[j])):
            if np.isnan(Ave[j][i])==True:
                del Ave[j][i]
                break
            c=c+1
```

It would be appreciated if anybody gives me a faster code.

Comment: are you using `numpy`? if yes, please update your tag.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Is the list always of length 8? Do the numpy arrays always only have 1 element? Some more elaboration can help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, this is one way.

Just note that holding a list of arrays is inefficient. It is advisable, where possible, to hold your data in a single `numpy` array.

```
from numpy import array, isnan, nan

Ave = [array([ nan]),
       array([ 0.03030303]),
       array([ 0.025]),
       array([ 0.03546099]),
       array([ 0.02877698]),
       array([ 0.05343511]),
       array([ nan]),
       array([ nan])]

A = array(Ave)
res = list(map(array, A[~isnan(A)]))

# [array(0.03030303),
#  array(0.025),
#  array(0.03546099),
#  array(0.02877698),
#  array(0.05343511)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehensions:

```
ave = [ [ n for n in row if not np.isnan(n)] for row in ave ]
```

Note that your sample data is a bit ambiguous as it is not clear if, by "Ave[0] is shown below", you mean to imply that the list has three dimensions or just two. It seams unlikely that you would want a 3D list with the second dimension containing lists of one-element arrays.  The result of the NaN clean up would produce rows with a list of arrays of 0 or 1 element.

If that is indeed what you're working with, then there would need to be one more nesting of list comprehension in the solution, at which point I would suggest breaking it into steps with intermediate results.

for example:

```
clearNaN  = lambda numberArray : [ n for n in numberArray if not np.isnan(n) ]
clearList = lambda arrayList   : [ clearNaN(arr) for arr in arrayList ] 
Ave       = [ clearList(row) for row in Ave ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `itertools.filterfalse`:

```
Ave
# [array([nan]), array([0.03030303]), array([0.025]), array([0.03546099]), array([0.02877698]), array([0.05343511]), array([nan]), array([nan])]

list(itertools.filterfalse(np.isnan, Ave))
# [array([0.03030303]), array([0.025]), array([0.03546099]), array([0.02877698]), array([0.05343511])]
```

Or if `Ave` is nested deeper:

```
AveAveAve = np.random.randint(0, 3, (5, 5, 1))
AveAveAve = np.random.random((5, 5, 1)) * AveAveAve / AveAveAve
AveAveAve = list(map(list, AveAveAve))
AveAveAve
# [[array([0.25051587]), array([nan]), array([0.93294353]), array([0.45979654]), array([0.46274847])],
#  [array([nan]), array([0.36631801]), array([0.18432189]), array([0.10408241]), array([nan])],
#  [array([0.73367427]), array([0.93523268]), array([0.33142847]), array([nan]), array([0.84569255])],     
#  [array([0.95316363]), array([0.67298091]), array([0.06368582]), array([0.22668049]), array([0.14361035])],
#  [array([0.66480064]), array([0.91260134]), array([0.10735208]), array([0.55708037]), array([0.6402967])]]

list(map(list, map(itertools.filterfalse, itertools.repeat(np.isnan), AveAveAve)))
# [[array([0.25051587]), array([0.93294353]), array([0.45979654]), array([0.46274847])],
#  [array([0.36631801]), array([0.18432189]), array([0.10408241])],
#  [array([0.73367427]), array([0.93523268]), array([0.33142847]), array([0.84569255])],
#  [array([0.95316363]), array([0.67298091]), array([0.06368582]), array([0.22668049]), array([0.14361035])],
#  [array([0.66480064]), array([0.91260134]), array([0.10735208]), array([0.55708037]), array([0.6402967])]]
```